# Pass an object of a type aggregated by a boost::variant to a function that accepts that boost::variant

Tags: c++, pass-by-reference, boost-variant

Suppose I have:

```
class TypeA { };
class TypeB { };
typedef boost::variant<TypeA, TypeB> Type;
```

1. This is ok:

   ```
   void foo(Type t) { };

   int main(){
       TypeA a;
       foo(a);
   }
   ```
2. This does not compile:

   ```
   void foo(Type &t) { };

   int main(){
       TypeA a;
       foo(a);
   }
   ```

   with the error:

   > invalid initialization of reference of type ‘Type&’ from
   >   expression of type ‘TypeA’
3. Also this does not compile:

   ```
   void foo(Type *t) { };

   int main(){
       TypeA a;
       foo(&a);
   }
   ```

   with the error:

   > cannot convert ‘TypeA*’ to ‘Type*’ for argument ‘1’ to ‘void
   >   foo(Type*)’

Is there a way to pass to a function that accepts a boost::variant an instance of one of the types aggregated by that boost::variant, either through a reference (as in case 2) or a pointer (as in case 3)?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What really happens in 1:

```
TypeA a;
Type __temporary__(a);
foo(__temporary__);
```

What cannot happen in 2 or 3:

```
TypeA a;
Type* __temporary__(&a);
  // this fails because there is no inheritance relationship
foo(__temporary__);
```

You have two solutions (for a non template foo):

- convert to `Type`, then take a pointer/reference to this
- create a `boost::variant<TypeA*,TypeB*>` for implicit conversion to kick in

A third solution is to change foo itself, and make it template. It depends on what you want to do.

Comment: Thank you! But what do you mean with `__temporary__` ? If you mean a compiler temporary object, wouldn't it be created only with a call to eg. "foo(TypeA());" ? In your first solution, does the conversion from TypeA to Type require a copy, eg. as in "TypeA a; Type t=a; foo(&t);" ? Nice your second solution, I'll think about it! As regards templates, how could I fit TypeA and TypeB which are unrelated  with no common base class?

Comment: @Francesco: The compiler copies `a` into a temporary object of type `Type` (the variant) and then performs the call to `foo` with this temporary object. // Templates are meant for unrelated types, as long as the methods required are present in both.

Answer (score 1):

Aggregation implies that the `boost::variant` contains both `TypeA` and `TypeB`. It doesn't. It contains either `TypeA` or `TypeB`. It's more like a union than a struct.

You can pass `TypeA` by value because there is an implicit conversion from `TypeA` to `Type`.

There is no implicit conversion from `TypeA&` to `Type&` (or `TypeA*` to `Type*`) and there shouldn't be. Think of what would happen if a reference to a `TypeA` object was passed into `foo()` and `foo()` decides to replace it with a `TypeB` value.

Without knowing what `foo()` and `TypeA`/`TypeB` are, I can't give you more specific advice but perhaps you can use a function template. i.e.

```
template <typename T>
void foo(T& t) {}
```

or overloaded functions:

```
void foo(TypeA& t) {}
void foo(TypeB& t) {}
```

Comment: Thank you! Overloaded functions could be a solution. As regards templates, how could I fit TypeA and TypeB which are unrelated with no common base class?

Comment: Templates do not care about the actual parameter types. The only thing that matters is that whatever operations you perform on the type-parameterized objects are valid for objects of the actual type. If the code for the two types is the same, use a template. Otherwise, overloaded functions might be the way to go.